# Is there a word that means "render dependent on"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I convince someone to abandon a contract for some product they were buying, and get that product from me instead, I have "made them dependent on" me. Perhaps I have "dependify'd" them.

Is there a real word with this usage?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Sounds like seduction or addiction.

Comment: That's definitely on the right track! Both those words have strong associations - I wonder if there is a more neutral word with the same function.

Comment: Making someone dependent on you is neutral?

Comment: Not entirely, but it has no inevitable associations (e.g. drugs, sex)

Comment: Could you clarify; is the contract for ongoing service, supply of the product or just a one off sale. Thanks

Comment: @elliot: Allow me. Yes, apparently, it's a continuing service. Like you used to buy coffee from someone. Then someone else came and offered you a better price. You agreed. Because of that your original supplier went out of business, and now it's either you keep buying from the new guy or renounce coffee altogether. He's your only option. You're totally dependent on him for your coffee.

Comment: Sort of like "enslave," but less harsh.

Comment: Informal: You have hooked them.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Yes, or "you've got your hooks into him," etc, etc, but the OP is looking for a SINGLE word.

Comment: @Ricky: *Hooked* is a single word. From the OP's example: _I have [**dependify'd**] them._ --> _I have **hooked** them._

Comment: One word, two words? Lighten up. We will not be enslaved by painting within the lines.

Comment: You have **won** them **over**.  Does the word you are looking for have to mean "dependent"? Just because I buy bread from a bakery does not make me dependent on the bakery, does it?

Comment: From the point of view of the previous contract holder you’ve ***stolen*** their client.  From your point of view you’ve ***acquired*** a new client.  From the point of view of the client, they’ve ***switched*** suppliers/vendors.

Comment: I'm particularly looking for an ongoing service (@Elliot), and (@fev) I am indeed looking for a sense of dependency - some suggestion that the disappearance of the service would harm the dependent party in some way.

Answer (score 1):

*Engender* or Enjoined is the word.

To enjoin them to buy from you is to cause or create a need for them to buy from only you. It is more polite than enslave but amounts to the same thing. So long as they need a product they will look to you. I hope you can be happy in serving them.

Answer (score 1):

I know no such word as you suggest. Two words come to mind:

You have *ensnared* them.

> Ensnare = to catch or get control of something or someone:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ensnare)

You may also have *enticed* them.

> Entice = to persuade someone to do something by offering them something pleasant
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english)

Which to choose? *ensnare* fits your example better.

I point out that you may ensnare (in a new contract) by enticing (with an attractive offer), but that you are unlikely to entice by ensnaring.

Comment: "Ensnare" is a brilliant suggestion! A quick lookup of synonyms gives some additional useful words, including "enmesh" and "entangle".